# Installing .net framework on Amazon EC2 windows server 2012

Tags: amazon-ec2, quickbooks

Need help on how to install quickbooks on amazon ec2 server.

I already installed the quickbooks enterprise 2014 but now i need to access the server by sharing it by accessing it via internet from our network.

I have found this http://www.qodbc.com/QODBCrds.htm and apparently when i tried to install it and execute it already ask for .net framework 3.5 which i cannot install.

Some says I have to execute this command

`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /Source:d:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess`

but I notice that it points to a source file of the windows install which i think i dont have since it is installed via ec2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to install the QB client locally and the server remotely, that won't work. QB doesn't tolerate internet latency, and this could result in corruption of your company file, if it works at all.